# How to uninstall Yarn from a project

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm a bit confused.

I accidentally installed yarn in a project. I just ran the command `yarn` that installed the yarn in the project. How do I uninstall yarn from the project?

Do I type in `npm uninstall yarn`? to uninstall it from a project?

I looked at other solutions and I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

- Run `npm uninstall yarn` make sure it no longer is listed in your package.json
- Delete the yarn.lock file if there is one

Answer (score 1):

If in linux (similar for others I guess):

- cd *project_directory*
- Run "npm uninstall yarn"
- rm -rf .yarn
- rm .yarnrc.yml
- rm yarn.lock
- in package.json: delete "yarn" lines
- in .gitignore (if present): delete "yarn" lines
- in README.md (if present): change "yarn" to "npm"
- run "grep -irl yarn ." to find any other references